# API result not integrated into popup

Tags: javascript, html, api

API answer is not integrated on click. Could you help me to find the issue please ?
API url is https://www.aviationweather.gov/adds/dataserver_current/httpparam?datasource=metars&requestType=retrieve&format=xml&mostRecentForEachStation=true&hoursBeforeNow=48&stationString=LFPG

Ans script is the one below.

```
<script>
  const lat = 49.004800830809685;
  const lon = 2.555933679530433;
  const mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([lat, lon], 7);
  L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
  }).addTo(mymap);
  const marker = L.marker([lat, lon]).addTo(mymap);
  marker.bindPopup("Loading temperature data...");
  async function main() {
    const mtr = await fetch(`https://www.aviationweather.gov/adds/dataserver_current/httpparam?datasource=metars&requestType=retrieve&format=xml&mostRecentForEachStation=true&hoursBeforeNow=48&stationString=LFPG`)
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(xml => new DOMParser().parseFromString(xml, "text/xml"));
    console.log(mtr);
    displayMETARINFO(mtr);
  }
  function displayMETARINFO(data) {
    const raw_text = data.querySelector("METAR raw_text").textContent;
    marker.bindPopup(`Current METAR:<br>${raw_text}`);
  }
  main();
</script>
```

Comment: In console log, I get aviationweather.gov/adds/dataserver_current/httpparam?datasource=metars&requestType=retrieve&format=xml&mostRecentForEachStation=true&hoursBeforeNow=48&stationString=LFPG' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: Not sure to understand well CORS policy, and issue actualy.

Comment: I added  {mode: 'no-cors'}  in code without better result :-(                                            await fetch(`https://www.aviationweather.gov/adds/dataserver_current/httpparam?datasource=metars&requestType=retrieve&format=xml&mostRecentForEachStation=true&hoursBeforeNow=48&stationString=LFBO`, {mode: 'no-cors'})

Comment: Anybody to help me please ?  Thank you :-)